# fantasy- looking for a zombie/supernatural book

Tags: story-identification, magical-creatures

The book has a college-age girl gets hired at a supernatural bookstore as a editor for a city guide, and involves zombies and other creatures. It also involves citywalkers who hear the personality/voice of the city itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like ["The Shambling Guide to New York City"](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/15790895-the-shambling-guide-to-new-york-city) by Mur Lafferty.

> A travel writer takes a job with a shady publishing company in New York, only to find that she must write a guide to the city - for the undead!

One of the reviews descriptions' highlights both the 'guidebook' part and the 'unusual bookstore' where she discovered the job.

> Zoe has returned to her hometown after an editorial job at a travel book publisher –and her affair with her boss–ended disastrously. She’s browsing an unusual bookstore when she notice a man posting a flyer seeking a guidebook editor. The advertiser and others attempt to dissuade her, but she perseveres, finally taking the job after an enlightening dinner with the new boss.

I found a reference to the city-talker element in the description of the second book (["Ghost Train to New Orleans"](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/18170139-the-ghost-train-to-new-orleans)) which I'll hide because it's possibly spoilery for events in the first book, though the citytalker concept possibly appears earlier.:

> her new-found ability to talk to cities seems to help.